# How to change file extensions on Debian Jesse

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn

I have a file that is a `.ovpn` and I want to change the file to a `.conf` file.  How do I change the file extension using the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mv` (move). It can be used for copying and for renaming:

```
mv blah.ovpn blah.conf
```

Depending on the access rights to that file you might also need to put `sudo` in front.